# Help center: Suggestions for order and structure of sections in the help center

Tags: discussion, help-center

In the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) there is

1. An [overview](https://stackoverflow.com/help) with a number of sections such as "Asking", "Our model" etc.
2. On [a detail page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), you can see the structure on the right (if using a large enough screen)

A different order is used here which I find confusing. Since there are 9 items (which is quite a lot), I think it would help to use the same order.

**Suggestions**:

- Use the same **order** for the sections on overview and detail pages.
- It might be helpful to have a page with a **list of all pages** (either with the sections as headers or just a plain old list with the titles as links)
- "Badges" and "Privileges" have only  one item each. Maybe they can be merged into "Reputation & Moderation" or this split into 2: "Moderation" and "Reputation & Privileges & Badges" and the "Badges" and "Privileges" merged into the latter.
- Personally, I would like to see a section "Editing" which would include formatting help ("[How do I format my posts using Markdown and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)", "[Markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)") and general information which applies to both questions and answers (and also comments). Maybe also conventions for editing (do not start edit wars, make bigger, complete edits vs. several small etc.)
- "Our model" is not something where I would look for most of the pages in there. Maybe a more general term such as "Basics".

---

Order on overview page:

1. Asking
2. Our model
3. Reputation & Moderation
4. Answering
5. Badges (1 item)
6. Privileges (1 item)
7. My account
8. Review Queues
9. Collectives on Stack Overflow

Order on detail page

1. Asking
2. Privileges
3. Badges
4. Our model
5. Reputation & Moderation
6. Answering
7. My account
8. Review Queues
9. Collectives on Stack Overflow

I would order it so that "Asking" and "Answering" come directly after the other and put them at the top, after "Our model", in any case before "Reputation & Moderation", but the current order might make more sense due to past experiences.

Comment: To have a real opinion on the specifics of what changes should be made, I'd have to spend much more time looking through the pages from an editing and organization standpoint, so I can't, at this time, reasonably comment on the specific changes you've mentioned. However, from what you've presented, it's clear that the current organization is … sub-optimal and that your suggestions have substantial merit, IMO. What seems to have happened is that the help center has grown organically over time, but has reached the point, again, where it could use an overall organizational edit/adjustment.

Comment: As I recall, the CMs have recently put substantial effort into editing the individual pages, and continue to do so. That is and has been very helpful and greatly appreciated. It looks like there have been enough changes over time such that the overall organization could use some attention.

Comment: @Makyen In that case, should I delete this suggestion? It does not make much sense then.

Comment: SE spending some time on the overall organization, which appears to me to be the base of what you're suggesting, seems to make quite a bit of sense to me. Bringing that to their attention, through having your question here, is a good idea, IMO. I certainly wouldn't delete this question. It's really easy to not realize that the overall organization could use some work with something like the help center when it's been growing organically for a while. In such projects, people tend to work on one page at a time, which can focus their view such that the overall organization *tends* to lag.